# Synchronized database

Tags: database, jsp

PC1 and PC2 in different location both have my offline application (JSP, record storage). And I would like to put the database in DROPBOX or using a VPN used by the application for synchronizing the database. is it possible??

Comment: Your question is not clear (at least to me): what are pc1 and pc2? web applications? "offline"? Which kind of database are you talking about?

Comment: im using wamp server, yeah it's web application and I would like that my database is in the DROPBOX not in my localhost. Computer 1 and computer 2 has the same database that store in the dropbox

Comment: wamp means Windows-Apache-MySql-Php why did you tag this post with "Jsp"? That has nothing to do with jsp.

Comment: i think u did not get my point... lol, how can my jsp access the database without wamp???

Comment: im just asking if database stored in DROPBOX used by two pc from different place is possible so that it can update real time...

Comment: Ok, now it's more clear :D A database that is "one single file"? I assume you are using Microsoft Access. The answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Microsoft Access and therefore your database is 1 single file. IN this case:

1. Put your file in a dropbox folder
2. Lets suppose in PC1 that will be downloaded to folder X
3. Map that file as ODBC source assigning a name (say "MyDb")
4. Create your web application in Java, deploy it in a container (Jetty? Tomcat?) and define a datasource that uses JdbcOdbc driver.

Of course,

- 2-4 needs to be done in every PC*
- not really sure what happens (probably somethign bad) if: PC1 open the file, PC2 open the file, PC1 changes something on the database, dropbox replaces it on PC1 with a newer version

Comment: oh I see, im using Glassfish (default in Netbeans), how can I put the localhost/phpmyadmin in dropbox?

Comment: <sql:setDataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/healthlink?autoReconnect=true"
                   user="root"
                   password=""/>

im using this code and I want the localhost to be in dropbox so that there's only 1 database used by 2 pc's...